# how to restrict taskbar display while using spefic application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia

I am using the [PyQt4](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt4/) application for ubuntu18.04 LXDE on Nvidia Jetson Nano 2GB.
I wanted the taskbar to be forcefully hidden while running the PyQt4 application.

How can I configure my LXDE desktop in this way?